# exe file is unable to start as a service

Tags: windows, debugging, visual-studio-2012, dll, kernel

For the same code, there are two exe files.One is old which has been created by someone and another is new. old one is able to run as a service. and new one is terminated unexpectedly. But the source code is same. Old exe is generated by compiling with old visual studio and wdk version and new one is generated with the help of VS-2012 and wdk-7. Is this problem because of dlls or something else. May you please provide me the way through which I can at least find the problem.

Comment: At an absolute minimum we need to know what error codes are produced when you attempt to start the service.  Check the event log too.

Comment: @HarryJohnston : "error 1067 process terminated unexpectedly"

Comment: The problem might be that the runtime library isn't installed on the target system.  What happens if you just run the exe file directly?

Comment: @HarryJohnston this exe is run by one service. when i run service it gives error. 
But when i just run exe, cmd flashes and than end of exe. and the same case ocurs for working exe. but it works with service